# cross compile ROS on Nao

Tags: cross-compilation, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to cross-compile ROS on my Nao robot.
The wiki on http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling says that I need Aldebaran's Cross-Compile-Toolkit (CTC) for the job.
Does anyone know where I can download CTC?
It seems http://users.aldebaran-robotics.com/ doesn't provide CTC.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9858/cross-compile-ros-on-nao/) by [jsuow](https://answers.ros.org/users/484/jsuow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On http://users.aldebaran-robotics.com/ you need to navigate to Software --> Download --> All Downloads --> your desired version (older ones are in Archives) --> Linux --> find the CTC in the list of files.

For example this is a link to the directory containing CTC v1.10.25: http://users.aldebaran-robotics.com/index.php?option=com_docman&task=cat_view&gid=26&Itemid=

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2011-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsuow](https://answers.ros.org/users/484/jsuow/) on 2011-05-01**:
Thanks a lot~~~

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-01**:
@ThomasK thanks for the double reply.